# change String[] into Vector<String>

Tags: java, string, vector

How can I convert in the quickest way `String[]` to `Vector<String>`?

Comment: why do you want to convert it to Vector and not to List?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With Arrays.asList :

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(yourStringArray));
```

---

**Resources :**

- [javadoc - Vector(Collection) constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector(java.util.Collection))
- [javadoc - Arrays.asList()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))

Comment: Beat me to it, and provided a better answer using typed collections as well as javadoc reference.

Comment: Note that `Arrays.asList()` will throw if the array is `null`.

Comment: Does Arrays.asList(T ..) respect the element's order?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above you can get a List created for you using Arrays.asList and then forcefully create a Vector. But, my question is if you absolutely need to use a Vector. Vector is synchronized http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html and you might not want this overhead. But, if you need synchronization would you consider developing againt the interface List and then use Collections.synchronizedList to achieve the synchronization?
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29

If you are using an API which requires the type Vector then this is of course not a choice...

Answer (score 1):

```
Vector v = new Vector( Arrays.asList(array) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

`Vector<String> strings = new Vector<String>( Arrays.asList(yourStringArray ) );`

Answer (score 1):

Check this example : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/ConvertanArraytoaVector.htm

It will look like :

```
    String[] arr = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```